# Remote mysql database connection in nodejs

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, database

I wanna connect with another server database. for example the code is in abc server and i want database of another server which is xyz server. I have done it. but getting error as

> Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'cp'

where i do have a database as **CP**

the server code to interact is

```
var db_config={
  "domain" : "http://****/",
  "hostname" : "****",
  "port"     :  3306,
  "user" : "*****",
  "password" : "****",
  "database" : "cp"
}

    var connection=mysql.createConnection(db_config);
    connection.connect(function(err,s){
      if (err){
        console.log("Error"+err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("db connected");
      }
    });
```

when i remove the database and the credentials are correct i could connect with server. if i use **information_schema** as db name also the db is getting connected properly. but when i use the other database i am still facing the error as

> Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'cp'

I have made setup for remote access in the particular server and checked in php code, its working fine over there.

Kindly help in this hectic task.

Comment: Did you add credentials on the remote db for your user and ip-address? It sounds like you have the credentials to connect to the mysql server but not to access the cp database.

Comment: Make sure that mysql user 'root' have remote connection permission.

Comment: @grim Yes, i have access to the mysql server but not the database. have added the credentials on the remote db.

Comment: @NashirUddin I haven't provided for the root user. instead i gave permission for the specific user created. So are you sure it will work when we give permission to root. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @NashirUddin On giving permission to 'root' user and using the credentials i am getting access denied error  >Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) but i can able to connect the database through php code

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you did to give permission to your user on the remote database?

Comment: @grim We gave grant permission to the ip which we call the remote server mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: I tried on another server with same methods. there node is not even connecting to the mysql server it gives error as access denied ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'mytest'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your grant statement was specified incorrectly (If it is exactly as you show it in your comment above).

It should read:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

However, these are very general privileges. I would suggest restricting it to a specific database:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE  ON <database>.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%';
```

After your set up your database, normal users shouldn't need to create or modify tables or grant access to other users.

Also, as you can see, I do not specify the password in the grant command. This should be specified in the CREATE USER command as under certain circumstances, GRANT may be logged in server logs or on the client side history files, which means that cleartext passwords may be read by anyone having read access to that information.